# Windows 8.1: Windows + I, then clicking on network, does nothing

Tags: networking, windows-8, charms-bar

I'm running Windows 8.1 and occasionally have noticed the following:
1. I press Windows + I to bring up the charm
2. I then press the network icon (in my case the wireless symbol) to bring up the network screen in the charm.

Often this works, but sometimes when I press the network charm, nothing happens at all. Repeated presses don't do anything. Sometimes waiting for 10 minutes will make presses work (something timing out?) but sometimes even that doesn't work.

Any suggestions for debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restart Windows Explorer:

1. Go to **Task Manager**.
2. Go to the **Processes** tab.
3. Find the process Windows Explorer, right click, choose **Restart**.

It seems to fix other related problems as well, so this might work.

Comment: This worked! I had tried a lot of other things but not this (lingering memories from older Windows versions where restarting Windows Explorer would break the taskbar or create other display problems). But this time, no display problems and it solved the issue. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: No problem! If you ever encounter an unresponsive Start button(bottom left), this does the trick too! Actually it should even work for anything controlled by Windows Explorer :)

Comment: This is a good way, but it does not fix it constantly. Do you know about the reason of this problem? Or how it can be fixed forever?